# Node.js multiple requests - no responses

Tags: node.js, python-requests, axios

I am trying to get data from web API with axios (Node.js). I need to execute approximately 200 requests with different URLs to fetch some data for further analysis. I tried to use multiple libs for http callouts but in every case i have the same issue. I did not receive success or error callback. Request just stock somewhere.

```
async function sendRequest(url) {
  let resp = await axios.get(url);
  return resp.data;     
}
```

I am calling this function in foor loop

```
for (var url in urls) {
   try {
     setData(url)         
   } catch (e) {
     console.log(e);
   }
}

async function setData(url) {
   var data = await sendRequest(url);
   // Set this data in global variable.
   globalData[url] = data;
}
```

I often received this error:

> `Error: read ECONNRESET`

I think this is all connected with too many requests in small interval.
What should I do to receive all requests. My temporary fix is to periodicly send 20 request per 20 seconds (still not ok, but I received more responses). But this is slow and it takes to many time.

However, I need all data from 200 requests in one variable for further analysis. If I wait for every request It takes too many time.